# (QTUM) I deployed a contract, used the jsonrpc callcontract to set a value, but got null

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
set 'hello world' for description() to contract 
qcli callcontract 816e13de2966cc56ca330d089aab849e5928eed5 90c3f38f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000

getDescription()
qcli callcontract 816e13de2966cc56ca330d089aab849e5928eed5 7284e416
```

Output: `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Why does it not return the same as the `set` method? Whatever I set, it returns 000.

I've already spent a whole day on this, please somebody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the callcontract can not change data, should call sendtocontract

and then this is a wrong call 
qcli sendtocontract 8a0795de06d66bf20940f5ee35b9092483af82a5 90c3f38f 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000

it should be
qcli sendtocontract 8a0795de06d66bf20940f5ee35b9092483af82a5 90c3f38f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20576f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
the method and param shouldn't have space

Answer (score 0):

I’m not a QTUM expert, but it looks like you’re using the wrong API.

> Mostly, you'll be using two RPC calls to interact with a contract's
>   methods:
>
> - callcontract to invoke a method in "query" mode, using data from your
>     local blockchain, but not making changes to it. This is free.
> - senttocontract to invoke a method in "commit" mode, creating a
>     transaction that changes the blockchain. This costs you gas.

`callcontract` appears to be for calling constant functions. If you’re making changes to the blockchain (sending a transaction), you need to use `sendtocontract`.

Comment: when i use qcli callcontract it success ,bu use sendtocontract it occurs that     /dapp # qcli sendtocontract 8a0795de06d66bf20940f5ee35b9092483af82a5 90c3f38f "0x90c3f38f0000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e59388e5938800000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
error: Error parsing JSON:0x90c3f38f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e59388e593880000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: i use sendtocontract to set '1', the output did changed to 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000...... but how can i put a string value